# Identifying poor performance in an Application

Tags: monitoring, performance-testing, performance

We are in the process of building a high-performance web application.

Unfortunately, there are times when performance unexpectedly degrades and we want to be able to monitor this so that we can proactively fix the problem when it occurs, as opposed to waiting for a user to report the problem.

So far, we are putting in place system monitors for metrics such as server memory usage, CPU usage and for gathering statistics on the database.

Whilst these show the overall health of the system, they don't help us when one particular user's session is slow.  We have implemented tracing into our C# application which is particularly useful when identifying issues where data is the culprit, but for performance reasons tracing will be off by default and only enabled when trying to fix a problem.

So my question is are there any other best-practices that we should be considering (WMI for instance)?  Is there anything else we should consider building into our web app that will benefit us without itself becoming a performance burden?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on your application, but I would always suggest to add your application metrics into your monitoring. For example number of recent picture uploads, number of concurrent users - I think you get the idea. Seeing the application specific metrics in combination with your server metrics like memory or CPU sometimes gives valuable insights.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to system health monitoring (using Nagios) of parameters such as load, disk space, etc.., we

- have built-in a REST service, called from Nagios, that provides statistics on

  - transactions pers second (which makes sense in our case)
  - number of active sessions
  - the number of errors in the logs per minute
  - ....
  - in short, anything that is specific to the application(s)
- monitor the time it takes for a (dummy) round trip transaction: as if an user or system was performing the business function

All this data being sent back to Nagios, we then configure alert levels and notifications.

We find that monitoring the number of Error entries in the logs gives some excellent short term warnings of a major crash/issue on the way for a lot of systems.

Answer (score 0):

Many of our customers use Systems and Application Monitor, which handles the health monitoring, along with Synthetic End User Monitor, which runs continuous synthetic transactions to show you the performance of a web application from the end-user's perspective.  It works for apps outside and behind the firewall. Users often tell us that SEUM will reveal availability problems from certain locations, or at certain times of day. You can download a free trial at

SolarWinds.com.

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion. _You must disclose your affiliation in your answers_.